# How can i send multiple data with one submit?

Tags: javascript, html, list, google-chrome, dom

I would like to send multiple data in one submit
so, I used chrome Dev tool "Console" and pasted this code

```
document.getElementsByName("f_coursecode")[0].value = "0032002";
document.getElementsByName("f_section")[0].value = "5";
document.getElementsByTagName ("form")[0].submit();
```

when form is submitted the page refreshes and data appears on table with 1 list
but the problem is I want to add more than one list. Like

```
document.getElementsByName("f_coursecode")[0].value = "0032002";
document.getElementsByName("f_section")[0].value = "5";


document.getElementsByName("f_coursecode")[0].value = "0034550";
document.getElementsByName("f_section")[0].value = "3";

document.getElementsByTagName ("form")[0].submit();
```

then, i want it to appear on table with 2 lists
can i do that ?

Comment: if you dont want to refresh your page & loose your data then , on submit write e.preventdefault() which will not reload your page

Comment: still for your question ..we can send multiple data in one using Array of object.

Comment: @imdisney **Array of object** is also need to be supported by Backend, please provide him full details that he need to make changes on backend

Comment: @JayVaghasiya do you know that his backend doesnt supports that ...and is it really  you saying that array of object will not support ..it is just he have to do manipulation on the data & send it how he want to send ...!!!

Comment: @JayVaghasiya if you can see his problem statment i have already told him somthing to do , and if you are aware about his problem you should help him instead of pointing me  .

Comment: @imdisney Yes i think you are right, sorry mate 

Comment: so if i am a user not backends i can't send multiple data through html dom ? sorry if i understand something wrong. @imdisney

Comment: @ChiradetLamlong did you try doing it 
document.getElementsByName("f_coursecode")[1].value = "0034550";
document.getElementsByName("f_section")[1].value = "3";
because by adding to 0th index again you are just overriding the existing list values

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementsByName("f_coursecode")[0].value = "0032002";
document.getElementsByTagName ("form")[0].submit();
```

```html
<form method="post" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="f_coursecode[]">
  <input type="text" name="f_coursecode[]">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```